# Facebook permissions for user_likes without offline_access

Tags: facebook, authentication, user-profile

We are in the process of adapting our application to deprecate offline_access.  Basically, our app allows users to join / approve the application and then browse for other users to match with.  The key is that users can look at other users profile information (likes,books,activities,movies,etc) from within our application.

My question, now that we cannot use offline_access, how can I ensure that users will be able to see other users information within the application for at least 60 days (the length of the new extended token).  Do I just make the call to get that new token?  Do I store it somewhere?  Or is that new token only needed to take actions on the users behalf but not to see their profile information?

Any help is appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using user `access_token` to retrieve [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)'s [`likes`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes).

Once you have extended the lifetime of `access_token` you need to store it on your end to be able to use it in the future. You may extend the lifetime once a day (but you doesn't required to, and may do it until it's valid).

Read the documentatio on [Deprecation of Offline Access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) for more details and [How-To: Handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) blog post (tokens expire not only on expiration date).

Comment: I have a quick follow up on that.  Upon testing a bit further, it seems that just using the standard application token I can access a users likes.  I did this test by 1) remove the application permissions from account A, 2) go in with account B, cannot see user's likes, 3) regive account permissions with account A, 4) now I can see user likes of account A with account B, but just by using the FB PHP SDK token thats passed for the logged in user.  Is that supposed to work like that?

Comment: @Michael, yep. You may use any user `access_token` to get `likes` of users who granted `user_likes` permission. Actually nothing said about this in documentation but if you'll use application `access_token` results will be empty, so user `access_token` is required (but not required to be for same user who granted permission). IMO this is a bit cumbersome...